# How to add label for each bar in barplot lan

Tags: r

i want to add label for each bar with Y value

[image: dataset]

[image: Barplot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add y values to `barplot()` with `text()`attribute on a new line like follows in this example:

```
library(tibble)
df <- data_frame(month=month.abb[1:12], Freq=c(12, 11, -5, 3, 4, 1, 43, 5,60,34,-4,3))
p<-barplot(df$Freq, col = rainbow(20), ylim=c(-10,60), names.arg = df$month, space=0, axes=F)
xval = seq(-5, 60, 5)
axis(side = 2, at = xval, labels = FALSE, xpd=T)
axis(side = 2, at = xval, tick = FALSE, labels = xval, xpd=T)
text(p, df$Freq + 2*sign(df$Freq), labels=df$Freq, xpd=TRUE) #this is the line of your interest in regards to the value labels
```

[image]